# Issue using <lightning:clickToDial> on a custom component with OpenCTI

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, opencti, softphone

I'm trying to use  in some of my components after having set up a Call Center with OpenCTI. I have the Phone utility placed on the app and am able to use it with any SF Lists or Record pages without any issues but when I go to my components that have the  fields, they are disabled. If I go to a separate page and refresh there (like one of the list views) and then click the home button, my components work fine.

What could be causing this issue?

I placed a callback in the enableClickToDial call to verify that it is going through successfully, it returns success on the page holding my components.

Is there something else that needs to be set up to use

Comment: Where is your component placed?